# Misplaced Notification Panel Button in Android KitKat

Tags: android

Since a week, this button is misplaced, looks like it has no right padding or something. The first time I installed this ROM (CyanogenMod 11) it worked fine, but now I have no idea why it happens and how to fix it. It works fine, but looks strange. I would like to know why does this happen and how to fix it. Here's a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it yesterday. This is the explanation: In some non-english versions of Android KitKat some dates like 2nd September ("2 de Septiembre" in Spanish) are too long for the date gap, so it misplace the right icons.
Some possible solutions are:

- Increasing the system DPI.
- Changing the system font family.
- Re-translating the languages file.
- Downloading a customization app.
- Installing another ROM.
- Or just, letting it (it works fine anyway)